# Converting c# eventhandler code to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, addhandler

What would be equivalent code in `vb.net` for the code below

```
dacServices.Message += new EventHandler<DacMessageEventArgs>(dbServices_Message);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
AddHandler dacServices.Message, AddressOf dbServices_Message
```

Most of converters do not work because you don't write new EventHandler in vb.net.

But you can see an example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

and for regular code conversion I use this converter:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/