# porting C# code to vb.net -- eventhandler

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to port following code from C# but have no idea! how it will translate as a eventhandler

**C#**

```
Select+=new EventHandler(OnSelectEvent);
if (!isMainMenuItem)
    {
        OwnerDraw=true;
        MeasureItem+=new MeasureItemEventHandler(OnMeasureItem);
        DrawItem+=new DrawItemEventHandler(OnDrawItem);
    }
```

**Ported Code:**

```
  [Select] += New EventHandler(AddressOf OnSelectEvent)

    If Not isMainMenuItem Then
        OwnerDraw = True
        ' AddHandler Menuitem.select, new measuritemeventhandler(addressof onmeasureitem)
        MeasureItem += New MeasureItemEventHandler(AddressOf OnMeasureItem)
        DrawItem += New DrawItemEventHandler(AddressOf OnDrawItem)
    End If
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The += marks cannot be used in VB.net you must use the AddHandler command.
it is not the same syntax.

```
AddHandler MeasureItem, AddressOf OnMeasureItem
```

Read this [Topic 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx) [Topic 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
it may help you

The same Issue is found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354696/converting-c-sharp-eventhandler-code-to-vb-net)